# jQuery onClick Move this element to top (as first Child of UL)

Tags: jquery

OnClicking on any `<li><a>....</a></li>` element except last child, this element should be moved to top as first child of `<ul>`.

---

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ofsn8jfy/1/)

---

> **Description**

By Default:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">02</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">03</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">04</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">05</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">06 (Last Child)</a></li>
</ul>
```

If I click on `03`, this list should become as below..

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">03</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">02</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">04</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">05</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">06 (Last Child)</a></li>
</ul>
```

But If Click on last child `<li>` this element should not be moved or changed... last child should remain as last always.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have a click event for li element except last element using `$('li:not(:last)')` element selector. and then use prependTo for appending as first child to parent:

```
$('li:not(:last)').click(function(){
 $(this).prependTo($(this).parent());
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0wc0qxwf/)**

**Update: Solution for targetting multiple UL elments**

In case for multiple UL elements, you need to use `:last-child` instead of `:last`.As `:last` targets last element in matched set whereas `:last-child` will target all li that are last child.

Comment: Just a warning about it, though: this does work only as long as there is only one ``<ul/>``. In case there are several, the ``:last`` applies to all ``<li/>``, not only those in the current ``<ul/>``. You can duplicate the HTML part of the fiddle if you want to understand the problem.

Comment: `:last-child` will do the trick in that case. i did not added that part as op didn't mentioned about multiple.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about this selector. It seemed implicit to me that this should apply to one or several specific ``<ul/>`` (using an ID or class? ``$('ul.reordering li:not(:last-child)').click(...)``) and that the last child should be fixed in each of these (the OP did call it _Last Child_, which is close enough to the selector to give a hint). Thanks for having updated your answer. I updated your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0wc0qxwf/2/) in order to demonstrate the applying to only specific ``<ul/>`` and ``:last-child``. Share if you deem it useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:not(:last)` filter and jQuery `prependTo`:

```
$('li a:not(:last)').click(function() {

    $li = $(this).parent('li');

    $li.prependTo($li.parent('ul'));

    return false;
})
```

Comment: Thank you all... How can I implement the same in this [FIDDLE] (http://jsfiddle.net/99b28z9y/8/) ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8eqg2uzy/)

This works as per suggested. Just add the `jquery` to your code

Comment: Thank you... How can I implement the same in this [FIDDLE] (jsfiddle.net/99b28z9y/8) ?